# Why xdebug.so does not exist in no-debug-non-zts?

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I have tried to install xdebug on Mac OSX Mojave with MAMP. I've previously installed xdebug but I've decided that it's better to use MAMP rather than creating my own local server.

I've managed to match MAMP's PHP version with my Mac. I'm using 7.3.1 and I've tried to change the php.ini configuration by enabling xdebug.

When I typed php -v in my terminal, I got this warning:
`/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.3.1/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so, 9): image not found`

I've checked the no-debug-non-zts-20180731 folder and all of the files are there except xdebug.so.

I'm not sure why it's not there at all. I find it really odd.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I've realised that xdebug's MAMP does not support PHP 7.3.1. So I have to downgrade it to PHP 7.2.14 to make it work.